# Installing ant on macos with brew gone wrong?

Tags: macos, ant, installation, homebrew

```
nma-2:test nikolaialeksandrenko$ brew install ant
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.0-bin.tar.gz
==> Best Mirror http://apache.igor.onlinedirect.bg/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.0-bin.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Download failed: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.0-bin.tar.gz
```

I'm trying to install ant on my mac with brew ...
I'm i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you make a brew update before installing it? Does this maybe fix your problem: http://superuser.com/questions/610157/how-do-i-install-ant-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Post it as an answer so i can market and correct :)

Comment: updating brew also helped in my case for installing hadoop

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should first try to make an update of brew:

```
brew update
```

If this does not work, have a look here for alternative installation: https://superuser.com/questions/610157/how-do-i-install-ant-on-os-x-mavericks

Comment: I even had problems executing "brew update" due to some folders having wrong access permission. Run "brew doctor" and it will warn you about the folders you need to change